# WP Job Manager - Job Type - Metakey value

Tags: wordpress

I am using a WP Job Manager plugin and I've just enabled the listing Types feature.

I setup a few listing types and now I need to output the value of the filed, but I'm not able to find the right meta_key value for the job types.

Anybody knows what the Metakey for WP Job Manager listing types is?

Comment: Look in the database using phpmyadmin.  The table you are looking for is probably called wp_postmeta.  Use the post id which you can find in the URL when you are editing your post and then in search for that post id in your wp_postmeta table.  The Sql query should return all of the post meta associated with that post.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know your post id, you can add this to your template.  If your post id was 333, then you can do this:

```
<?php

$post_id = 333;
$meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );

echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $meta );
echo '</pre>';

?>
```